# Accessing Azkaban's "runtime properties"

Tags: azkaban

I've been trying (with no luck) on a simple topic: Accessing Azkaban's "global" runtime properties (supposedly available to the flow). I've tried every normal and abnormal methods to try to access them from within a flow to no avail. Does anyone have a concrete example (no "hand waving" please) of how I might access them (maybe even to print one to a log file)? BTW, it is not a problem to access them from a different program after the flow has already run, (eg: REST API), but I'd like to get them during run, so I can create logs, etc, (this method does not work during runtime).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You create a job with the following content:

```
type=command
command=./first.sh ${azkaban.flow.start.minute}
```

In the shell script you can write the runtime property to your log file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Minute: $1 >> your.log
```